# Private Swift Pod with ObjC static libraries

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to create a private pod that ships with two static libraries.

Source of the pod is in swift however it depends upon two third party static libraries on which I have no control.

Linting my podspec, I get the following error just for the second lib (with a modulemap)

```
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  TestKit/TestKit/SSAIPolicy.swift:11:8: error: no such module 'SecondLib'
```

[image: Project Structure]

And, here is the source part of my podspec file:

```
  spec.source_files  = 'TestKit/*', 'Vendor/**/*.{h,modulemap}'
  spec.vendored_libraries = 'Vendor/FirstLib/libService.a', 'Vendor/SecondLib/libManagement.a'

  spec.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-ObjC' }
```

Note: I am able to use this framework just fine by compiling and dropping it manually in the main app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs to know, I got it working by changing **'Target Membership'**
 of header files in my library from **'Project'** to **'Public'**